# How to delete cookies when browser is closed? ASP.Net core,C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, cookies, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to delete the cookie when my browser is closed in my ASP.NET Core MVC project
This includes the code that I used to create the cookie.

```
      var claims = new List<Claim>()
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,user.email),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role,user.roles)
                };
                    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    var princilple = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, princilple);

                        if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                        {
                            return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Home", new { user.id });

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return RedirectToAction("Details", "Home", new { user.id });
                        }


                }
                else
                {
                    TempData["Message"] = "Invalid Username/Password";
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home");
            }
```

Comment: you could remove it using js and the window before unload event, but if you are only wanting the cookie to persist for the duration of the browsing, why not use a session instead?

Comment: Why bother with a cookie at all if you only want Session level authorization?

Answer (score 4):

You are creating the cookie using `SignInAsync` without setting `IsPersistent` to `true` , it will give you a session cookie that goes away when you close the browser window , you don't need to control that yourself , please refer to [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-3.1) for details .

Comment: Session cookies are the de facto method (for many many years) of cookies that only persist while the browser is open (fsvo).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
$(window).unload(function() {
   $.cookies.del('myCookie');
});
```

Comment: What about HttpOnly cookies?